# SolrNet query filtered by specific field

Tags: solrnet

I can't seem to find anything online that allows me do this. Basically I'm doing a simple SolrQuery but I want to *only* get back results where a field is a specific value.

So to be more specific I want to execute a Solr Query where `field` is either A or B or C - Is this possible?

I think I'm going to need to do a `SolrQueryByField` joined with a `SolrMultipleFilterQuery` but not really sure of how to get about doing this.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

add values in `list<IsolrQuery> OredData` ex: `OredData.add(new solrQueryByField("field","A"))` and add rest of ur choices ,then add it to `solrMultipleCriteriaQuery(OredData,"OR")` and choose "OR" as showed , then ,call ur Query passing `solrMultipleCriteriaQuery(OredData,"OR")` to it.

hope that i helped ;)